# SwiftUI: Error al validar un if basado en que si hay o no una instancia

Tags: condiciones, swift, xcode

estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica en swiftui, hay una parte del código donde una instancia del reproductor (audioManager.player) de la cual dependen varios componentes, para no establecer el mismo valor constantemente envolví la parte de la reproducción en una condicional (if let player =  audioManager.player) basada en que si hay o no una instancia de “player”, pero al hacerlo el contenido desaparece de manera extraña, como si no existiera la instancia “player” o fuera negativa, lo probé solo validando una parte y me di cuenta de que todo funciona correctamente pero no se porque el contenido no se visualiza ni en el canvas, ni en el simulador. Les agradecería si me ayudan con una sugerencia o solución, todo es bienvenido. ;)

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

final class AudioManager: ObservableObject {
   
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    func startPlayer(track: String, isPreview: Bool = false) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: track, withExtension: "mp3") else {
            print("Resourse not found")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            
            if isPreview {
                player?.prepareToPlay()
            } else {
                player?.play()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Fail to initialize", error)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct PlayerView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var audioManager: AudioManager
    @State private var value: Double = 0.0
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    var isPreview: Bool = false

    
    let timer = Timer
        .publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
                
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    
//                    MARK: ** EL ERROR ESTA AQUÍ  **
                    if let player = audioManager.player {
                        Slider(value: $value, in: 0...player.duration)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.top)
                    }
                    
                } // VStack
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                
            } // VStack
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            audioManager.startPlayer(track: "meditation1", isPreview: isPreview)
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            guard let player = audioManager.player, !isEditing else { return }
            value = player.currentTime
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            PlayerView(isPreview: true)
                .environmentObject(AudioManager())
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Imagen del cavas]

Answer (score 0):

Solo te faltaría llamar al objeto `AudioManager` de la misma manera como lo haces en el `PlayerView_Previews`  pero en la App:

```
@main
struct TuApp: App {
    @StateObject private var audioManager = AudioManager()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PlayerView().environmentObject(audioManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Si le agregas el objeto directamente también funciona:

```
@main
struct TuApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PlayerView().environmentObject(AudioManager())
        }
    }
}
```